# Power BI Report builder vba "Select Case"

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, powerbi

I currently have a code that changes date to local time by adding 3h to current time.

```
=Format(DateAdd("h",3,Now()), "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") & " EET"
```

This works fine now, but the problem is that i need to have daylight savings time also taken into consideration. This means that i need to have a "Select Case" -statement, where i would evaluate:

```
if the date is between 27.3.2022 and 27.9.2022 +3
if the date is between 28.9.2022 and 26.3.2023 +2
if the date is between 27.3.2023 and 27.9.2023 +3
if the date is between 28.9.2023 and 26.3.2024 +2
```

and so on....

How do i write this in vb script (used in Power BI report builder)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Format()` is not a VBScript function, this looks like VBA and judging by the `=` Excel VBA at that.

Comment: The expression language for paginated reports is VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The expression language for paginated reports is VB.NET, so you can use the .NET [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) to find the right expression to convert the current UTC time to local time an a particular time zone, eg:

```
= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this solution is, that when I publish this to PowerBI Service, it uses the Power BI Service's default timezone, which can't be changed. Therefore the solution would need to be a static set of date-ranges which define the correct time zone despite having changes in the time due to daylight savings.